# Missing certain packages

Tags: unity, launcher

After I log in my menu that contains my: System, admimistration,update manager, etc; has disappeared, do you know what happened here. I really need this package especially for my updates. Can you help me?

Comment: Sounds like you "unbuntu'd" it alright. Can you access the settings from the gear icon at the very top right of the screen? Also, what version of Ubuntu are you running please?

Comment: Can you post an immage here?? or provide a link to the image(a screenshot of the menu) its not quite clear from your question what you are trying to say...

Comment: do as gksu update-manager in your terminal , is it opening ??

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to identify packages missing from the default install is to install and run synaptic. Software Center is a replacement for Synaptic but you'll do no harm using it. When you run synaptic you'll find menu items on the left. Under the `Custom Filter` option, the first menu item is "All" and the second is "Broken". The menu item you want to select is "Missing Recommends". You'll now have a list of packages That have been removed from the initial install. Check the boxes for any packages you wish to install. To apply the selected changes click the "apply" icon. It should be the 3rd from the top left, hover over the icon to make sure its the apply function. You may also want to check if there are any broken packages.